# How can I use the pumping lemma for context-free language in a language with two alphabets?

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

$G =\{aba\mid a\in \{x,y,z\}{^+}\text{  and } b \in \{0,1\}\}$

I have watched many videos but I never saw an example of someone solving a pumping lemma in a language with two alphabets, can someone give me a example or some guidance? I need to prove if it is a context free language, there are other ways?

Comment: The language itself does not have two alphabets. The alphabet is $\Sigma=\{x,y,z,0,1\}$. The notation suggests, that before and after one 0 or 1 there is at least one x,y or z or any number of them, for example: $xzxy1xzxy\in G$

Comment: so should i pump something like ${x^k} z y 0^k {x^k} z y $?

Comment: There is only one $\texttt{1,0}$ in the middle of the word. Otherwise it's not in the language. You can show that a word $w=x^kyz1x^kyz\in G$, $\lvert w\rvert >k$ with the pumping length $k$ satisfies the four requirements of the lemma, but this doesn't mean that the language is indeed context-free. There are some languages which satisfy the context-free Pumping-Lemma although they aren't context-free. In order to really prove that the language is context-free you could provide a grammar $V$ which satisfies $L(V)=G$.

Comment: Addition: a context-free grammar of course.